# Excel Sum Array from different cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've been searching for an answer on my latest problem in almost three days now. I can't find a solution for my wishes below anywhere

Normally we plan our employee how much to work 4 weeks ahead, but sometimes it could be anything from 2 to 12 weeks ahead.
We have a total worktime per year around 1950 to 2010 hours, these will be spread for all 52 weeks depending on some holiday days and so..
All employee are allowed to work plus-minus 15h/week, but at the end of year the remaining time must be 0:00

Row 2 is how many hours we normally should plan to work that specific week
Row 5 to 11 is how many hours our employee actually worked in that week.

example

- If cell C1 is 4, the arrayformula should be (G5:J5   G6:J6  and further..)
- If cell C1 is 7, the arrayformula should be (G5:M5   G6:M6  and further..)

I would like to enter a week number in specific cell (or at least a column-letter-value for what week, C1 or C2) and automatic SUM
all persons actual workhours to thooe weeks and compare it with row2 for the same amount of weeks

The formula should look something like `=SUM(G5:´C2´5)` where C2 is my last week value

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:
`=IF(ISBLANK(C1),"",SUM(G5:OFFSET(G5,0,MATCH(C1,G2:N2,0)-1)))`
C1 is the last week as you wrote
G5 is the first week of the first name
G2:N2 you can change N2 to the last week if you have more weeks
Offset will find the column number corresponding to the value in C1

You should use absolute references to copy the formula down, use the following:
`=IF(ISBLANK($C$1),"",SUM($G5:OFFSET($G5,0,MATCH($C$1,$G$2:$N$2,0)-1)))`

[image]